# How i can fetch fields from models and calculate some filed and pass them to my template?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

my model.py

```
class Main(models.Model):
    name= ....
    amount      = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=40000)
```

In my views:

```
def mainf(request):
    listmain = models.Main.objects.all()
    for data in listmain:
        value   =   data.amount * 5
    calculated_data = data_and_value  

    context = {'main':calculated_data}
    return render(request,'main/main.html',context)
```

How i can fetch fields from models and  calculate some fileds and pass them(calculated_data) to my template?

For example i want to calculate salary base on hours. i want to fetch hours from database and calculate hours*500 and then send hours and salary to my template.

`data_and_value` can be object or anything. i want get this and send to my template

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you trying to annotate each object with `value`? Are you trying to sum `amount` from each object?

Comment: Can you add fields to your model to give a proper example, for example your model with hour/pay/whatever fields, example data, expected output and the template you want to use? It's hard to tell if you want to annotate a queryset with a calculated value for each object (salary for each user) or want just a single aggregated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either define them as properties on the model, or pass them through the context to the template.

If the value is based purely on fields in one model instance, it's good to define a property. For example,

```
class Thing( models.Model)
    # Thing has height, width, depth fields
    ...
    @property
    def adjusted_volume(self):
        return (self.height+10) * (self.width+10) * (self.depth+10)
```

In your template (and indeed in your code) you can now refer to `{{ thing.adjusted_volume }}`, assuming `thing` was included in the context, either explicitly,  or by a class-based-view's `context_object_name="thing"`

Your question shows an example of passing the result of a computation that's not restricted to a single object instance to the template where you can refer to it as `{{ main}}` (But the code is incorrect, `value` gets repeatedly calculated and then thrown away in a loop, and `data_and_value` is not defined).